# Compare two columns, identify duplicates and select a larger integer if available in the other column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I tried to word the question as best I could but I appreciate it might not be very clear.

I have the following table

| original_ctr_id | ctr_id |
| --- | --- |
| 906 | 906 |
| 905 | 905 |
| 904 | 904 |
| 903 | 903 |
| 902 | 902 |
| 901 | 901 |
| 900 | 900 |
| 898 | 899 |
| 898 | 898 |
| 897 | 897 |
| 896 | 896 |
| 895 | 895 |
| 894 | 894 |
| 893 | 893 |
| 892 | 892 |

I'm trying to run a query that will check if there are duplicates in original_ctr_id and if so, replace that number with the highest corresponding number in ctr_id.

In the example above, 898 occurs twice and the highest corresponding number in ctr_id is 899, so the table should look identical, however 898 does not appear at all and would be replaced in 1 row with 899.

This is just a small extract of the table as an illustration for what I'm trying to do. I've tried Partition by and Group by but I don't need ctr_id to be aggregated so that won't work as far as I know.

The query that is the closest to what I need is below, if I could somehow add some logic to select ctr_id instead of original_ctr_id when it's larger, this should give the desired result.

```
SELECT 
     original_ctr_id
FROM [MIS].[dbo].[Test]
GROUP BY 
    original_ctr_id
HAVING 
Count(original_ctr_id) >= 1 
ORDER BY original_ctr_id
```

Does anyone know if this is on the right track or have an elegant solution?

Comment: You seem to have multiple requirements here.  It would be helpful to include better sample data.

Comment: As a start, add max(ctr_id) to your `select`ed columns

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen
The question came to me from a colleague and this was all the sample data I've been given unfortunately

Comment: T-SQL is used by several products, such as SQL Server, Sybase and Azure Synapse. What (R)DBMS product are you using?

Comment: Can't you use an updatable CTE here?

Comment: @Larnu SSMS. I looked at a CTE but couldn't get it exactly as I wanted. If that's the best way to go about it I'll try and have a look at what I did wrong.

Comment: SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) isn't a (R)DBMS, @Elarbe , it's an IDE like application. Telling me you are using SSMS, is like telling someone you are using "Visual Studio" when asked what programming language you're using.

Comment: @Larnu
Right, sorry. Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: based solely on the data provided ... `update [MIS].[dbo].[Test] set original_ctr_id = ctr_id where original_ctr_id != ctr_id`; assuming OP comes back and says this is invalid ... how is it invalid (ie, what other details are we missing? could we get a more representative set of sample data?); on the other hand, if this is a valid solution ... why does the table have two columns to store the same value?

Comment: could you have a scenario where there are more than 2 rows with the same `original_ctr_id`? or are you guaranteed to have at most 2 rows with the same `original_ctr_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a guess, what you want here is an updatable CTE. This would work in SQL Server, but might not in a different product that uses T-SQL like SyBase:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT original_ctr_id,
           ctr_id,
           COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY original_ctr_id) AS originals,
           MAX(ctr_id) OVER (PARTITION BY original_ctr_id) AS max_ctr_id
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
UPDATE CTE
SET ctr_id = max_ctr_id
WHERE ctr_id != max_ctr_id
  AND originals > 1
```

Comment: If I do this and then `SELECT DISTINCT ctr_id FROM Table`, this actually gives me the result I would want in ctr_id. 
I think this is the best answer I'm going to get so thank you. Will accept it now.